# Can't See Rect Shape on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use the canvas tag and fillRect of JavaScript to draw a grid on screen, but so far all I see is a blank canvas.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="gameScreen" width="550" height="550"></canvas>
        <script src="grid.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

grid.js

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

let width = 50
let margin = 5

for(var row = 0; row<10; row ++){
    for(var column = 0; column < 10; column++){
        ctx.fillRect(column * (width + margin), row * (width + margin), width, width)
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem, yet when opening the html file in my browser all I see is the blank outline of my 550x550 canvas.

Comment: Can you look at the develipper yools of your browser? Particularly the network tab and the js console.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, what information am I looking for in these two sections?

Comment: If your script got fetched correctly (200) and if it did execute without an error. If both these conditions are met, then try to remove the `type` attribute from your script tag.

Comment: works fine for me: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/grid/index.html tested in Chrome and Firefox